# JTag Debugging with Eclipse Mars CDT : "Program file does not exist"

Tags: arm, eclipse-cdt, cortex-m, jtag, segger-jlink

I have successfully compiled an ARM embedded project, next files has been created:

```
MyProject.elf
MyProject.bin
MyProject.hex
MyProject.map
MyProjectmd5.bin
```

Then I am going to `Run ->  Debug Configurations -> GDB SEGGER J-Link Debugging -> New -> Debug` and I get the error:

```
 Program file does not exist
```

The GCC Compiler for ARM used: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

ARM Eclipse plugins used: http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/

and that's what I see in the console:

```
    23:25:36 **** Build of configuration Release for project MyProject ****
    make all 
    Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size
    arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "MyProject.elf"
       text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      40120     252    2252   42624    a680 MyProject.elf
    Finished building: MyProject.siz



23:25:36 Build Finished (took 112ms)
```

It seems that there is a problem running JLinkGDBServer

```
$ JLinkGDBServer
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V4.98e Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V4.98e (DLL compiled May 5 2015 11:59:38)

-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file: none
GDB Server Listening port: 2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port: 2333
Accept remote connection: yes
Generate logfile: off
Verify download: off
Init regs on start: off
Silent mode: off
Single run mode: off
Target connection timeout: 0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface: USB
J-Link script: none
J-Link settings file: none
------Target related settings------
Target device: unspecified
Target interface: JTAG
Target interface speed: 1000kHz
Target endian: little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link OB-SAM3U128-V2-NordicSemi compiled May 4 2015 13:48:48
Hardware: V1.00
S/N: 681968347
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.30 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...ERROR: Could not connect to target.
Target connection failed. GDBServer will be closed...Restoring target state and closing J-Link connection...
Shutting down...
Could not connect to target.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++ Application in Main TAB was missing.
OK using `Debug/MyProject.elf`